# Changing font in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

How can I put all data that are in a line in my GridView, in Bold style, if another column of this GridView has the value "1" for example ?

This columns, can't be visible to the user. 
I use SqlDataSource to fill my GridVIew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- Use the [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to inspect the data you're
  writing to each column (you'd check for the value "1", in your case).
- If your condition is met, set a flag.
- Once the flag has been set, you can check it on writing each new row
  (again, using the event detailed above). When writing the row you
  want to appear as bold, check the flag. If the flag is set, [change the CssClass
  property of the Row object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.aspx) to a class you have created in your stylesheet, which has
  `text-weight:bold` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set font and other style information on each cell, which you can fetch with `table.Rows[row].Cells[col]` where row/col are your row and column numbers.

Here's the documentation for `TableCell`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.aspx

You should also be able to set the styles per-row by using the `GridViewRow` class exposed by `table.Rows`. Here's the link ot the MSDN article for it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {            
           if (((myobject)e.Row.DataItem).myfield == "1")
           {
              e.Row.CssClass="myclass";
           }             
        }
    }
```